# AWS CLI not working on Mac OSX Yosemite: "-bash: aws: command not found"

Tags: amazon-web-services, python-2.7, pip, command-line-interface

I've successfully downloaded the AWS CLI using PIP onto Mac OSX Yosemite. I'm running Python version 2.7.

I can see the AWS executable in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`.

But when I try to run

`aws help`

in my Terminal to test that the AWS CLI works, I get

`-bash: aws: command not found`

Why isn't this working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin` will need to be in your path. In your `~/.profile` file (create one if necessary) add a line like:

```
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:$PATH"
```

Open a new Terminal window and it should work.

Comment: Ah thanks, that worked! I had tried a similar line in my ~/.profile but this one worked.

Comment: Since I installed `aws` cli tool for my user only I had to do this: `export PATH="$HOME/Library/Python/2.7/bin:$PATH"` instead. I did this on MacOS Sierra.